# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath fails

Tags: ios, swift3

My implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't work.
On the other hand, implementation of swipe does.
I want to present another page when a table row is clicked.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let  tableCell: SearchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchcell") as! SearchTableViewCell


    if(self.searchstatus == "people")
    {
        if(useridarray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSString != "null" )
        {

            self.searchdelegate.otheruserid=useridarray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSString;
            let ProfilePageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherprofile")
            self.present(ProfilePageViewController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(useridarray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSString != "null")
        {
            let hashtag1=search.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
            self.searchdelegate.hashtag="\(hashtag1)" as NSString!
            self.searchdelegate.hashtag=searchdelegate.hashtag.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces) as NSString!
            self.searchdelegate.hashtag=searchdelegate.hashtag.replacingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSString!
            let hashtag = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hashtag")
            self.present(hashtag!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace didSelectRowAtIndexPath and use didSelectRowAt (swift3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this method which are swift3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 }
```

Comment: Mouni ... please check that is your tableView selection set to false....
 
add these lines in your view did load
tableView.allowsSelection =true;

Comment: Ok Mouni I want to see ur code and also you should check your storyboard as if there is disable selection from storyboard

Comment: @shafi My code is above the question... And I Select the Storyboard is single selection in my dabledata

Comment: @shafi In my code I fix the breakpoint, but Did select Methods does not entire it.

Comment: @mouni which method you are using? please comment here

Comment: Now only I insert the class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,**UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,**SINCallClientDelegate {

Comment: But still it's not work for me. I run in the code in xcode 7.3 it's work it!!. After convert the code in swift3.0 it's not work??